# Flush buffer for QProcess in PyQt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, raspberry-pi, pyqt5

I have a Python 3.4 app using the PyQt5 framework and I'm having an issue.

I setup a QProcess:

```
def listenToServer(self, MainWindow):
    self.ws = QtCore.QProcess(self)
    self.ws.start("python3 /home/pi/scara_panel/ws.py")
    self.ws.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self.processServer)
```

And it calls this function:

```
def processServer(self):
    income = str(self.ws.readAllStandardOutput())
    print(income)
```

On a desktop, it works fine. It flows into to the app. However, when the program is run on a Raspberry Pi, it only displays what its read once the script ws.py terminates.

I've read that this has to do with output buffering in Python. I've tried things like adding the -u flag, but no dice. Any suggestions on how to clear this buffer when using readAllStandardOutput()?

I've tried implementing a few things from [Disable output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/python-output-buffering) but nothing seems to fix the issue.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can get your output to flush immediately via

```
print(income, flush=True)
```

For more info see [How to flush output of Python print?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print)